# Applescript is too slow to do anything and keeps timing out

Tags: events, timeout, applescript

Can anybody shed some light on why scripting is so slow all of a sudden?

Even this test script does not complete before a 120 second time out.

```
tell application "Mail"
set selectedEmails to get selection -- returns a list
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with your system. That script does not take much time to execute on my computer.

```
set time1 to do shell script "perl -e 'use Time::HiRes qw(time); print time'"
tell application "Mail" to set selectedEmails to get selection -- returns a list
set time2 to do shell script "perl -e 'use Time::HiRes qw(time); print time'"
set millisec to (round ((time2 - time1) * 1000))
return "Emails:" & (count of selectedEmails) & " Milliseconds:" & millisec
```

"Emails:1000 Milliseconds:183"

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried running your snippet directly from AppleScript Editor and it works of course. So I pasted my complete script in and ran it. That also works. But when I try either from Script Debugger 4.5, neither work. So I've narrowed it down to that. I think it must be compiling differently in Script Debugger and that version does not work.

Comment: I didn't realise that there is a totally new version of Script Debugger than fixes this problem. I've just tried version 5.03 and it works as expected.